# Elementary Matricies

Tags: matrices

> Consider an elementary matrix that is identical to the identity matrix except that one of the entries in the main diagonal is $k$ rather than $1$ (this matrix corresponds to the elementary matrix associated with multiplying a row by a number while doing row reduction). Can this matrix be expressed as a product of elementary matrices that do not have this property (that is, the matrices that represent switching rows and adding one row to another)?

What I am trying to do is to see whether there is a smaller set contained in the set of all elementary matrices that functions as the the set of all elementary matrices does.

Comment: yes, any operations other than just scaling a row by a non zero value

Answer (score 0):

All the other operations are equivalent to multiplying by a matrix of determinant $\pm 1$, while your matrix has  determinant $k$. So, no, you can't do it when $k \ne \pm 1$.